Elegant derivation of area of an arbitraty 2D shape
Formula to derive
Assume that we have an arbitrary nice 2D surface $S$ embedded in $\mathbb{R}^3$ parametrized as follows:
$$
f\,:\,S\ni(\xi,\eta)\longmapsto(x(\xi,\eta)\,,\,y(\xi,\eta)\,,\,z(\xi,\eta)) \in \mathbb{R}^3
$$
Now to calculate it's surface area A there is a formula($J$ is a Jacobian of $f$):
$$
A=\int_S \sqrt{\det(J^T J)}
$$
Where $J^T J$ is a metric induced from a trivial metric on $\mathbb{R}^3$, $\;g=\textrm{d}x\otimes\textrm{d}x+ \textrm{d}y\otimes\textrm{d}y + \textrm{d}z\otimes\textrm{d}z$.
Brutal derivation
Vector normal to the surface is:
$$
N = f_*\partial_\xi \times f_*\partial_\eta
$$
($f_*$ is a pushforward along $f$) and then normalize $n=N/\sqrt{g(N,N)} = (n_x,n_y,n_z)$.
One can than deduce the surface form $\omega$, following the equality $\omega(X,Y)=\sqrt{g(X\times Y,X\times Y)}$ where $X$, $Y$ are some arbitrary vector fields on the tangent bundle $TS$. This gives
$$
\omega = n_z \textrm{d}x\wedge \textrm{d}y + n_y \textrm{d}z\wedge \textrm{d}x + n_x \textrm{d}y\wedge \textrm{d}z
$$
now the surface is
$$
A=\int_{f(S)} \omega = \int_S f^*\omega 
$$
and after some fun time rewriting pullback $f^*\omega$ gives $\sqrt{\det(J^T J)}$.
$\square$
Question
I would really appreciate if someone can find a more elegant derivation of this formula that does not require explicit calculation.
Possible hint
An easy calculation of a pullback $f^*g$ gives a $J^T J$, which means that the pullback of a metric in $\mathbb{R}^3$ to $S$ is a volume form in $S$, but up to this moment we can say that after the derivation. An argument supporting this claim would finish the proof without calculations, but up to this moment I cannot find one.
Side quest is to find a proper citation of this derivation to implement this into Wikipedia. Because for now, a formula for a surface area of an arbitrary surface is written poorly and I would like to fix it, with proper, elegant proof.
Up to this moment on pages related to calculating the surface area of a given surface it is just stated that $J^T J$ is a metric on an induced surface.

The final sentence is incorrect. You should read about the Gram determinant. Given a $k$-dimensional parallelepiped in $\Bbb R^n$ spanned by vectors  $v_1,\dots,v_k$, you find that its $k$-dimensional volume is $\sqrt{\det(J^\top J)}$, where $J$ is the $n\times k$ matrix whose columns are $v_1,\dots,v_k$.

right, if I understood you correctly I have fixed the problem.

First of all, a volume form on a $k$-dimensional manifold must be a $k$-form, not a function. Second, you're thinking of the metric tensor as $J^\top J$ (written in terms of the parametrizing coordinates).

yes my bad, language sometimes can be difficult :),
$\sqrt{\det(J^T J)} \textrm{d}\xi\wedge \textrm{d}\eta$ would be a volume form

Right. At any rate, see this post for a complete discussion of this stuff.
